# advanced workflow sample example

Tags: alfresco, jbpm

some sample examples to develop advanced workflow deploying it in alfresco server using jbpm and connectivity to database

Regards,

Comment: I would also appreciate a general workflow example ;)

Comment: @daemonfire300 Have a look at the BPMN examples on wikipedia (or Google) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Modeling_Notation#Examples_of_business_process_diagrams

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you take a look in the alfresco configuration directory -WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\workflow for the workflows bundled with Alfresco.

it has a bunch of examples.  Also check out  [Jeff Potts' blog](http://www.ecmarchitect.com) - he wrote a great article on workflow.  You can also get his book, which is great (it's based on some his blog entries, but a lot of material is reworked and lots more added).  Link to [book here.](http://www.packtpub.com/alfresco-developer-guide/book)